# Fetching offchain storage value returns different value than the value fetched using localStorageGet function

Tags: storage, offchain-worker, offchain-storage

I need to get the rpc_url value set initially from the explorer. The localStorageGet rpc function returns the correct value of the rpc_url.
This returns `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/MY_API_KEY`

But while fetching the rpc_url through the storage call like this:

```rs
    pub const ETHEREUM_EXECUTION_RPC: &[u8] = b"starknet::ETHEREUM_EXECUTION_RPC";
    let eth_execution_rpc_url = StorageValueRef::persistent(ETHEREUM_EXECUTION_RPC)
        .get::<Vec<u8>>()
        .map_err(|_| OffchainWorkerError::GetStorageFailed)?
        .ok_or(OffchainWorkerError::EthRpcNotSet)?;
    
     let endpoint: &str =
        core::str::from_utf8(&eth_execution_rpc_url).map_err(|_| OffchainWorkerError::FormatBytesFailed)?;
```

This returns `endpoint = ttps://eth-mainnet.g.alche`

I've checked the offchain storage docs and I think I'm querying the value correctly.